# Correctly position tooltip for absolutely positioned element

Tags: css, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I have an absolutely positioned element I want to show a tooltip for. The tooltip is not aligned to the element when I show it. How can I make it align correctly?

CSS Code:

```
#content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

JSX Code:

```
const { IconButton, TooltipHost, Fabric } = window.Fabric;

const styles = {
  root: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  icon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20
  }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fabric style={styles.root}>
        <TooltipHost content="The tip">
          <IconButton style={styles.icon} iconProps={{ iconName: 'Org' }} />
        </TooltipHost>
      </Fabric>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content />,  document.getElementById('content'));
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/evantrimboli/pen/OoVEaL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that seems to work. I added a `div` wrapper around the `TooltipHost`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxVWdz

```
const { IconButton, TooltipHost, Fabric } = window.Fabric;

const styles = {
  root: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  iconWrapper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
  }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fabric style={styles.root}>
        <div style={styles.iconWrapper}>
          <TooltipHost content="The tip">
            <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Org' }} />
          </TooltipHost>
        </div>
      </Fabric>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content />,  document.getElementById('content'));
```

I haven't worked with the library (Office UI Fabric) before, so it's possible there's a better way.